# exclude "On Hold" orders from Woo Sales reports

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, report

I want to remove/exclude any orders with the order status "On Hold" from woocommerce sales reports. By default On hold orders are included in the sales reports.

There is a function "exclude_from_order_sales_reports" found here - https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_register_order_type.html - that will exclude a post type from sales reports.

Also the woo order types and order status are handled here - https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_register_order_type.html#167-221

Unfortunately my php coding is basic (im still learning) and i have no clue where to start with all this code. How can I use the above function to remove on hold order from sales reports?

Answer (score 1):

i seen on woocommerce main report class `WC_Admin_Report` on line `67` they have filter like this `$order_status = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reports_order_statuses', $order_status );`

so i think you can easily alter the default order status for reports by adding filter like this on your `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_reports_order_statuses', 'my_custom_order_status_for_reports', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_order_status_for_reports($order_statuses){
    $order_statuses = array('completed'); // your order statuses for reports

    return $order_statuses;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an updated version of this? Can't seem to get it working with Woo 2.6.11. Thanks!